# Starting issues

Tags: battery

I have a 2008 328i bmw. Some days my car will start with no problem. And then there are those days I need a jump. All of my lights come on, my dash board does not dim. Anyone have a solution?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! You should have your battery checked, especially if it's over 5 years old. Take it somewhere they can do a load test on it.

Comment: What is  a load test

Comment: They put the battery onto an apparatus which can test the battery under load. It gives the overall health of the battery without hurting it.

Comment: It is also possible that one of the electrical connections in the battery end of things (battery to ground, battery to starter, starter solenoid wiring) is poor, and affected negatively by temperature or humidity changes or movement. Open, clean, and reconnect each of them.